# Is there a function in excel to automatically calculate age using date of birth?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

what function on excel can calculate age in the age column using data in the date of birth column?

There is a table for clients, Column D is for Date of Birth and Column H is for Age; What function or formula can I use in excel to automatically calculate Age in Column H using the Date of Birth in Column D?

I've not tried any function yet.

Comment: `=DATEDIF(DOB,TODAY(),"Y")` is the usual one I think

Comment: Just a point here, many results can be obtained by combining functions so we don't need specific functions for every task...

Answer (score 2):

Don't know of a function but =INT((YEARFRAC(TODAY(),B3,1))) where cell B3 contains a date like 01/01/1970 will return age in years.

Comment: today(), good one, I thought about the same but with now()...